# How to create Web Authentication for Corda RPC Users?

Tags: java, corda

Using the webapp, which uses corda-webserver, how to implement authentication mechanism for `RPC` Users?

RPC Users mentioned in the configuration file.

And perform role based actions(Only accessible flows).

I could only find detail about authenticating RPC Users through `ClientRPCOps`, but couldn't find anything about web based authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web authentication is not directly related to Corda. Connecting to a node via rpc requires authentication. Anything past that is not Corda's problem.

If you want to setup web authentication, then you should look into how frameworks like Spring or Ktor handle these scenarios. Corda is not web based by default and requires integration into a "web server" application to be web-enabled.